# Prove that identity matrix is the only idempotent $n x n$ matrix that is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

I do get that let's say 
$A=(A*A)$

$A^{-1} * A = A^{-1} *(A*A)$

$(A^{-1}*A)=(A^{-1}*A)A$

Then $I=I*A$, therefore $I=A$

Are those correct? Is there another or proper way to prove this?

Comment: That's perfect, and I suspect that is as good a proof as you're going to get.

Comment: There are probably plenty of ways to over-optimize a three line proof, but what is the point when there are more exercises to tackle? :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your proof is great, and completely correct.  Personally, I object to the use of $*$ as denoting matrix multiplication, but that's more an opinion that anything.

---

Another version of the proof that I like is as follows:

Let's say that $A$ is invertible with $A = A^2$. Then we have
$$
A^2 - A = 0 \implies\\
A(A - I) = 0 \implies\\
A^{-1}[A(A - I)] = A^{-1}[0] \implies\\
A-I = 0 
$$
So, we must have $A - I = 0$, which is to say that $A = I$.

Why do I like this better?  I suppose the approach generalizes nicely to arbitrary polynomials and the consideration of minimal polynomials, but really I just think factoring is neat.

Answer (score 2):

You can also prove it without any calculations whatsoever, by thinking of idempotent matrices as linear transformations on R^n, rather than as matrices. A is idempotent if, and only if, it acts as the identity on its range. Thus, if it's not the identity, then its range can't be all of R^n, and therefore it is not invertible.